# How to use the GridView events

Tags: c#, events

I have .aspx page . that Have the GridviewChild within another gridviewParent. My GridviewChild has Columns with some controls, out of which it has DropDown controls. I want to fill the Data in dropdowns

```
GridViewParent
           GridViewChild
                     Columns
                        DropDownControl
```

This is hierarchy that I want to explain. On which event of which Grid I can do fillDropDown? Also how to get selected value (Which Events)? If possible send me code in C#

Comment: I would politely suggest that you mark a few more answers to your questions as "accepted".

Comment: ok I will, but those must satisfy me right ? This will wrong if I do so by those not satisfied.Also lot of question i asked but getting no answers..so how i can do that dear,...  Well Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RowDataBound event of the GridViewChild control to fill the drop down lists.
To get the selected value of a drop down list u can say something like this:

```
DropDownList ddl = GridViewParent.GridViewChild.Rows[someRowIndex].Cells[someCellIndex].FindControl("DropDownlist1") as DropDownList;
string v = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I hope that was beneficial to u.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the child gridview with parent data:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <GridView id="childGrid" .. DataSource='<%# Eval("Items") %>' ItemDataBound="child_itemdatabound">
<ItemTemplate>
```

And then proceed to bind the DDL in the itemdatabound event:

```
.. child_itemdatabound(..)
{
   DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddl") as DropDownList;
   if (ddl != null)
   {
      //Load from data source
      ddl.DataSource = dal.GetData();
      ddl.DataBind();

      //You can set the selected value here too; e.Row.DataItem represents the bound data object
   }
}
```

You can also get the selected value in the same way, as mentioned in the other post.